# solr function query demoting based on a field value range?

Tags: solr

In my solr ranking function, I want to demote large documents. So for example, if a document is bigger than 1000 characters or less than 100 characters, I want to demote the score by half. Is there any readily available function query or should I build a new ones

Answer (score 0):

you can always add an indexed field with the length of the doc, and then use that one for boosting accordingly.

It is quite easy to do that with [UpdateRequestProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor) or just [ScriptUpdateProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ScriptUpdateProcessor)